# Count Rows from a separate dataframe with conditions - PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, count, pyspark

I have an airline booking transaction dataframe with columns as `customer_id, date_of_travel, dest_country`. I have another dataframe with hotel booking transaction details with `customer_id, date_of_booking, dest_country`.

I need to bring a column into the airline booking dataframe which would be count of all hotel bookings made for that `customer_id` in the same country within 1 month (+/- 30 days) of the `date_of_travel`.

I have added 2 additional columns to my airline booking dataset for Date_before_30_Days and Date_after_30_Days. I am having trouble understanding how do I get the counts for hotel bookings in the same country within 1 month of airline travel.

#### Airline Data

```
Customer_id Country     Date_of_Travel
xyz     US      10-20-2018
abc     MX      03-04-2018
xyz     US      04-05-2019
```

#### Hotel Data

```
Customer_id Country     Date_of_Booking
xyz     CA      03-30-2018
xyz     US      05-01-2018
xyz     US      10-15-2018
abc     PH      10-20-2018
abc     MX      03-01-2018
```

#### Final Output

```
Customer_id Country     Date_of_Travel      Total_Hotel_Bookings
xyz     US      10-20-2018          1
abc     MX      03-04-2018          0
xyz     CA      04-05-2019          1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Example you have provided is having the different output than you mentioned in statements. For eg.)  The customer id `"abc" in "MX"` country is actually having hotel bookings on `1st March` and he also have ticket booking on `4th March` as per Airline data. Which is actually falling in (+/-) 30 days range.

By understanding your statements, I have made below example.

**Airline Data**

```
airline_data = pd.DataFrame({"Customer_Id":["xyz", "abc", "xyz"], "Country":["US", "MX", "CA"],"Date_Of_Travel":["10-20-2018", "03-04-2018", "04-05-2019"]})

print(airline_data)

Customer_Id Country Date_Of_Travel
xyz         US      10-20-2018
abc         MX      03-04-2018
xyz         CA      04-05-2019
```

**Hotel Data**

```
Hotel_data = pd.DataFrame({"Customer_Id":["xyz","xyz", "xyz","abc", "abc"], "Country":["CA","US","US","PH","MX"],"Date_of_Booking":["03-30-2019", "05-01-2018", "10-15-2018", "10-20-2018", "03-01-2018"]})

print(Hotel_data)

Customer_Id Country Date_of_Booking
xyz         CA      03-30-2019
xyz         US      05-01-2018
xyz         US      10-15-2018
abc         PH      10-20-2018
abc         MX      03-01-2018
```

Convert the Date column from string to Datetime object

```
airline_data["Date_Of_Travel"] = pd.to_datetime(airline_data["Date_Of_Travel"])
Hotel_data["Date_of_Booking"] = pd.to_datetime(Hotel_data["Date_of_Booking"])
```

Create two columns for Minimum date and Maximum date which is (+/-) 30 days.

```
airline_data["Min_date"] = (airline_data["Date_Of_Travel"]) - pd.Timedelta(days=30)
airline_data["Max_date"] = (airline_data["Date_Of_Travel"]) + pd.Timedelta(days=30)
```

Join two dataframes based on the Customer_id, Country to get the required data

```
df_1 = pd.merge(airline_data, Hotel_data, on=["Customer_Id", "Country"],how="left")

print(df_1)


Customer_Id Country Date_Of_Travel  Min_date    Max_date    Date_of_Booking
xyz         US      2018-10-20      2018-09-20  2018-11-19  2018-05-01
xyz         US      2018-10-20      2018-09-20  2018-11-19  2018-10-15
abc         MX      2018-03-04      2018-02-02  2018-04-03  2018-03-01
xyz         CA      2019-04-05      2019-03-06  2019-05-05  2019-03-30
```

Create a column which is satisfying the condition of Booking is +/- 30 days from Travel date.

```
df_1["Bool"] = (df_1.Date_of_Booking >= df_1.Min_date) & (df_1.Date_of_Booking <= df_1.Max_date)

df_1["Bool"] = df_1["Bool"].apply(int)

print(df_1)


Customer_Id Country Date_Of_Travel  Min_date    Max_date    Date_of_Booking Bool
xyz         US      2018-10-20      2018-09-20  2018-11-19  2018-05-01      0
xyz         US      2018-10-20      2018-09-20  2018-11-19  2018-10-15      1
abc         MX      2018-03-04      2018-02-02  2018-04-03  2018-03-01      1
xyz         CA      2019-04-05      2019-03-06  2019-05-05  2019-03-30      1
```

Now, apply `groupby` on the df_1 and get the sum of the Bool to get the total bookings of Each customer in particular country.

```
Req_Results = df_1.groupby(["Customer_Id","Country","Date_Of_Travel","Date_of_Booking"]).sum().reset_index()

Req_Results = Req_Results[Req_Results.Bool!=0]

Req_Results.rename(columns={"Bool":"Total_Hotel_Bookings"},inplace=True)

print(Req_Results)


Customer_Id Country Date_Of_Travel  Date_of_Booking   Total_Hotel_Bookings
abc        MX       2018-03-04      2018-03-01           1
xyz        CA       2019-04-05      2019-03-30           1
xyz        US       2018-10-20      2018-10-15           1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and what I ended up doing. Could there be a less verbose way of doing it though?

Answer (score 0):

for each row of the airline_data you have to create filters in your hotel_data:

```
filter_id = hotel_data[Customer_id] == desired_id
filter_country = hotel_data[Country] == desired_country
filter_date = (hotel_data[Date_of_Booking] > start_date) & (hotel_data[Date_of_Booking] < end_date)
```

then apply the filters and count the results:

```
filtered_df = hotel_data[filter_id & filter_country & filter_date]
total_bookings = len(filtered_df)
```

of course you can do this with a loop and add the number of bookings to a list and at the end just add the list as a new column of airline_data.

Does this help?